# How to quickly assign {x:1,y:2} to {row,col}?

Tags: javascript

I want to quickly assign {x:1,y:2} to {row,col}, i.e. `let row = objXY.x, let col = objXY.y`.

I know the destructuring assignment can do this

```
let {x,y} = objXY
```

But is there any way to do like this?

```
let {row,col} = objXY
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign destructured properties to new variable names as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

For example

```
const obj = {x: 1, y: 2};
const {x: row, y: col} = obj;
console.log(row); // 1
console.log(col); // 2
```